# Diferencia entre instancias de PHP "new" y " : : "

Tags: php, mvc, pdo, php7

Hay dos maneras de acceder al resultado de una function que está dentro de una clase en PHP, la más común, que es instanciando la clase con la palabra reservada "new", y luego apuntando al método que tenga adentro dicha clase, y la otra que considero "igual" es llamando el nombre de la Clase + :: + nombre del método, ejm:

1)

```
$hola = new MiClasesita();
   $hola -> miMetodo();
```

2) `$hola = MiClasesita::miMetodo();`

Mi pregunta es, cuál es la diferencia entre los dos, o cuál es mejor usarla en cuál caso?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No son iguales realmente.

El operador doble dos puntos, conocido oficialmente como [Operador de Resolución de Ámbito](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), y llamado también curiosamente *Paamayim Nekudotayim* (doble dos puntos en hebreo), se usa **para propiedades y clases estáticas**.

Es así como está definido [su uso en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

> ... es un token que permite acceder a elementos [estáticos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php),
>   [constantes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.constants.php), y sobrescribir propiedades o métodos de una clase.

En cuanto a `new` se usa para crear instancias de clases que **no son estáticas**, así está [definido también en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php):

> Para crear una instancia de una clase, se debe emplear la palabra
>   reservada `new`. Un objeto se creará siempre a menos que el objeto
>   tenga un [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php) que arroje una [excepción](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php) en caso de
>   error. Las clases deberían ser definidas antes de la instanciación (y
>   en algunos casos esto es un requerimiento).

Por lo tanto, no es que haya que decidir entre uno u otro, sino que **cuando la clase o propiedad sea estática deberás utilizar `::` y cuando sea una clase no estática, debes usar `new`**.

PHP 5 era más permisivo y usar `::` en algunos escenarios donde no debería usarse, pero a partir de PHP 7 empezaron a poner restricciones en ese sentido y hay código que deja de funcionar o que emite advertencias de que se está usando mal el operador `::`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A. Cedano , en conclusión, el operador con los doble dos puntos lo empleo si o si voy a enviar parámetros en la función que estoy llamando (por ser una método estático al que estoy invocando) ?

Comment: @Candelo sí, las propiedades o métodos estáticos y/o constantes se llaman con el operador `::`, mientras que las propiedades/métods que no son ni estáticas ni constantes se llaman con el operador `->`

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es el proceso de la [instanciacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php) que es crear un objeto nuevo de una clase, con lo cual haces uso de la palabra reservada `new` para que ahora el objeto `$hola` pueda acceder al método `miMetodo();`

Lo segundo es acceder a un método estático dentro de una clase pero evitando el proceso de la instanciación.

Los métodos y propiedades estáticas deberán ser `static` en caso contrario obtendrás un `warning` de tipo

> **WARNING** Non-static method Human::hola() should not be called statically on line number #

Otro detalles es que la sintaxis para declarar una propiedad estática debe ser del modo

```
public static function miMetodo()
{
    /*has algo*/
};
```

Ahora para invocarlo es del modo

```
echo ClassName::miMetodo();
```